# Subquery returned more than 1 value after declare Startdate and Enddate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I just want declare between from start date and end date and I have SQL code like this:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom date, @DateTo date;

SET @DateFrom='10-15-2017';
SET @DateTo='10-20-2017';

WITH TB_BlockDate(date) AS
  ( SELECT @DateFrom
   FROM [dbo].[TB_BlockTanggal]
   WHERE Kode_Properti ='KP0062'
   UNION ALL SELECT DateAdd(DAY,1,TB_BlockDate.date)
   FROM TB_BlockDate 
   WHERE TB_BlockDate.date < @DateTo)
SELECT date
FROM TB_BlockDate OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

This code works if i just have single data row, like this:
[Database condition 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RifVL.jpg)

But if have multiple data rows, like this: [Database condition 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDKfZ.jpg)

It shows error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server? I have removed mysql tag as it seems like MS SQL server from the screenshot. If you are using mysql, you can remove sql-server tag, and add mysql through edit menu.

Comment: i using sql server..  then what i must to do?

Comment: That's fine. I have already updated the question with sql-server tag. Please avoid using mysql tag for questions relating to sql-server.

Comment: oh.. i'm sory... thanks for your attention..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for.

With the help of an ad-hoc tally table and a CROSS APPLY.  A tally/calendar table would do the trick as well.

Not exactly clear on your desired results, so I included all fields from your source ... `Select A.*`

**Example**

```
Declare @TB_BlockTanggal Table ([BlockID] varchar(50),[Kode_Properti] varchar(50),[KodeMember] varchar(50),[StartDateBlock] date,[EndDateBlock] date)
Insert Into @TB_BlockTanggal Values 
 (1,'KP0062','KM0005','10/10/2017','10/15/2017')
,(8,'KP0066','KM0005','10/17/2017','10/20/2017')

Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From  @TB_BlockTanggal A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[StartDateBlock],[EndDateBlock])+1) 
                       D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[StartDateBlock]) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

---

---

---

> **EDIT - If Interested in a Table-Valued Function**

I'll often use a UDF to create dynamic date/time ranges.  It is faster than a recursive CTE and parameter driven.

You supply the datetime range, desired datepart and increment.

Using the UDF approach, the query would look like this:

```
Select A.* 
      ,Date = cast(B.RetVal as date)
 From  @TB_BlockTanggal A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]([StartDateBlock],[EndDateBlock],'DD',1) B
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Comment: Thanks very much sir... worked with well.. thanks for your helping me. i already tried with option 1, i will try option 2.. thanks for your advice..